# How to retrieve results from an external php file (file upload)

Tags: php, upload

I am trying to post a file upload form to a php file that is located on another server but I do not know how to retrieve the results that are outputed using an iframe (i.e. basically a json object containing URL's being echoed by the upload.php). Is there any other way to retrieve the data?

code:

```
<form action="http://mydomain/upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" target="upload_target">
    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="1000000" />
    Choose a file to upload: <input id="fileName" name="uploaded_file" type="file" />
    <input type="submit" value="Upload"/>

 <iframe id="upload_target" name="upload_target" src="#" style="width:0;height:0;border:0px solid #fff;"> </iframe>
</form>
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you show us the code you use to perform the post operation, please?

Comment: Nevermind I found the answer lol I didn't realize that it was echoing it to the iframe. All I do is get the information inside the iframe

Answer (score 0):

Explode function just get the contents of the file you need with get filecontents then explode the part of HTML you need